# CentOS Increase / Partition Size

Tags: linux, centos, partition

One of our servers has a 20gb / partition and it is getting full. Is there any safe way to take some space from the 2TB /home partition and allocate it to the / partition without losing data?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to provide more information. Are you using LVM for / and /home filesystem? If yes this logical volume are on the same volume groups? Are you using xfs(you can't shrink it) or ext4 for / and /home?

Comment: Both / and /home are ext3 partitions. There is no LVM going on as far as I am aware.

Comment: without LVM you would need to backup the home partition, destroy the partition, extend the / as described here: https://thewiringcloset.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/extending-a-root-filesystem-in-linux-without-lvm/ and then recreate the /home and restore the backup.